# Name convention for properties that are another class with a similar name

Tags: c#, naming-conventions

I'm sure this has been asked before, but I'm having trouble finding any relevant answers - probably because the generic nature of the terms I'm using.

I have a class - let's call it `Foo`. Now a given `Foo` has a variety of properties that define it's nature. For the sake of argument, let's call them `Name`, `Inactive` and `Notes`. There can also be many varieties of `Foo`, which are each a `FooType`, for lack of a better word.

So, we have the following class definitions:

```
public class FooType
{
    public byte Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Inactive { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
}

public class Foo
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public FooType TypeOfFoo { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Inactive { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
}
```

Not exactly an ideal situation, I know. Sadly, the `Inactive` and `Notes` fields on `FooType` are a must, so I can't use an `enum` as I would like. My quandary, then, is that I'm having trouble figuring out a reasonably descriptive name for `TypeofFoo` and `FooType`. Calling them `TypeofFoo` and `FooType` is ugly and prone to confusion in the future, so I'm looking for alternatives.

Is there any sort of naming convention that covers this?

Comment: how about `public FooType Type { get; set; }`or `public FooType FooType { get; set; }` ?

Comment: My concern with `Type` is the potential confusion with `System.Type`. Likewise, `FooType` (the property) being confused with `FooType` (the class). For the record, the latter was how I had it originally. Am I overthinking it?

Comment: Naming depends on context. Name should mean what it stores. If that's a `Account` say `Account`. When  you give examples with meaningless type names like `FooType` you can't expect a good answer. I can see @dotctor has already given a good answer. That said, your question is subjective and thus off-topic.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel My question is specifically asking if naming conventions exist for this and, if so, what that might be. As such, it's definitely not subjective. Either they exist or they do not. For instance, whether .NET classes should be `camelCase` or `PascalCase` is defined by Microsoft's naming conventions, not a matter of personal opinion (even if developers are free to ignore said-conventions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no naming convention.  In fact, the .NET Framework itself does not avoid using properties that have the same name as their type and even [suggest it in some older guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fzcth91k%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

[`SolidBrush.Color`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.solidbrush.color%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[`Control.Font`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.font%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

It's not a fool-proof solution, and [may cause confusion in certain edge cases like calling static members](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/07/06/color-color.aspx), but it's not so bad that there's reason to avoid it categorically.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use polymophy to subclass `Foo` and use a factory with an enumeration `FooType` to create the objects. Your subclasses should override the general methods to add specific behavior.
But I think the context is important to choose the right pattern. Just using a special naming is confusing in my opinion and doesn't represent your intend of the classes.